# Fastest c# implementation for handling shortlink collisions

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq-to-sql, string-comparison

I am pre-generating short codes for a service I am building that shortens links. It isn't your usual link shortener, so I can't use off the shelf, as we need to handle close to 1000 shortens per second.

I have a service that runs every 12 hours to add another 200,000 shortlinks to the lookup table for fast generating the links.

As the table of shortlinks gets longer, the service takes longer and longer, to a point where we can't keep up with the demand for shortlinks being requested.

The table of shortened links is 1.8M rows. We have 280k links left before we run out. And it is taking more than 1 hour to generate 200k links now.

I am obviously doing something wrong, probably the fact that I am using just a `List<string>` to compare against.  Below is the block of code:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
LtsDataContext ldc = new LtsDataContext();
List<string> currentCodes = ldc.ShortUrls.Select(s => s.ShortCode).ToList();
currentCodes = 
    currentCodes.Union(ldc.FastShortCodes.Select(s => s.ShortCode)).ToList();

int count = args.Length > 0 ? int.Parse(args[0]) : 200000;

List<string> newCodes = new List<string>(count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    string newCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 8);
    while (currentCodes.Contains(newCode) || newCodes.Contains(newCode))
        newCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 8);
    newCodes.Add(newCode);
}

ldc.FastShortCodes.InsertAllOnSubmit(newCodes.Select(s => 
    new FastShortCode() { ShortCode = s }));
ldc.SubmitChanges();
Console.Write((decimal)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / (decimal)1000);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I haven't used linq-to-sql yet, but this looks like you would pull all links from the database... is that correct? Maybe it would help to see the real code you are using to insert the single links.

Comment: What list implementation is currentCodes?  Contains is  going to be relatively expensive (O(n)) on an ArrayList.  Perhaps you could use a hash table to get O(1) contains?

Comment: I'd be curious to see what kind of speed you get out of inverting your logic a bit.  Generate your new code and then do a count query to see if that new code already exists.  I suspect this will be faster, but I'm not sure how much faster.

Comment: Am I missing something here? 1000urls/second * 60sec/min * 60min/hr = 3600k URLs needed per hour. 200k per hour or every 12hrs isn't even close to fast enough for you.

Comment: @Michael - That was the problem, we weren't able to scale. Our users were using everything up, and the site would go down while we tried to add more links.

Comment: I see. I thought you were trying to maintain 200k/hr--I guess that was just an example of current performance being too slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that by using GUID fragments, you have to check for collisions against a larger and larger table.

I assume you don't want to create sequential keys because it's vulnerable to URL spelunking, but then you should start with something sequential and then obfuscate it.

**Edit**

Going with a commenter's suggestion, I would:

```
1. take a sequential key
2. shift left 8
3. add a random value between 0 and 255
4. encode base-62 (0-9,A-Z,a-z)
```

You will have no collisions, and the random bits will mean a person randomly trying URLs will only get one hit out of every 255 attempts.

Comment: Virtual -1. Likelihood of collision with 4 million values is less than 0.1%. 8 hex characters can support up to 4,294,967,296 variants.

Comment: @Aliostad: the problem isn't how many collisions, it's that he *must* check. Also, at 1000 shortens/second, he's going to reach 4M pretty quickly.

Comment: But this is what you are saying: "you are inevitably going to get more and more collisions."

Comment: I don't think you can differentiate between uppercase and lowercase letters in URLs. That will shrink your space quite a bit. Also, you don't need to check for collisions if you optimistically insert.

Comment: @John: he's generating *parameters* (which can be case-sensitive), not domain names (which can't). Many shorteners work this way.

Comment: @egrunin - While I don't like doing encoding like this, I can't help but also love how much faster... not 1 hour anymore 2 minutes! and it will scale linearly!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `Dictionary` for `currentCodes` and `newCodes`? The `Contains` method of a `List` needs to traverse all list entries O(n), in contrast to a `Dictionary`, which runs in O(1).

**EDIT1**
IF you are saving all your links in the database anyway, why do you need a Guid? Why don't you simply use the primary key of the database in your links?

**EDIT2**
Since the likelyhood that a code already exists is very low you could try an insert and catch the exception and then try it again (optimistic inserting).

Comment: When then shortlink table is inserted into, it grabs top X from fastshortcodes, then deletes them, so i don't have a way to do a constraint

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you're loading your entire table of short links (1.8 million) into a List and then searching it with a Contains function, which as @Jeff Foster pointed out is an O(n) operation.

Why not use a more optimistic method? In your database, add a unique constraint to the ShortCode column of the ShortUrls/FastShortCodes table. Then simply generate new short codes and attempt to insert them. If they fail the unique constraint (which shouldn't happen too often) then just catch the exception and try again.

I also agree with @egruin that by using a substring of a GUID you are limiting yourself to only fifteen characters (0-9, A-F). I would look for a way to use at least all alphanumeric characters (0-9, A-Z) which would significantly reduce the number of collisions you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem in this line:

```
currentCodes.Contains(newCode) || newCodes.Contains(newCode)
```

This will take more and more with each addition which describes the problem. I doubt if you are interested in mathematical complexity of this, but this would be close to (N*N)/2.

Solution is to use `HashTable`.